# Saving an image as bmp file in Photoshop CS on Mac

Tags: mac, adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5, bmp

I have a Mac and I am trying to save my Photoshop CS5 extended file as a BMP. When I click *save as* the only ones available are Photoshop, Large Doc, Photoshop eps, JPEG, JPEG 2000, Photoshop DDF, Photoshop 2.0, Photoshop raw, Scitex, Tiff, and Photoshop DCS.

But there's no option to *save as* bmp. Is there a way I can save it like that?

Comment: Did this ever work for you in the past? Are you sure you're not referring to [.BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) (bitmap) file?

Comment: Yes, it is a BMP

Comment: What format (color mode, bit-level, etc.) is your image set to in Photoshop? I don't think PS supports 32-bit BMPs, so if it's set to a 32-bit mode in PS, they may not offer BMP as a "save as" option.

Comment: I haven't used photoshop much, but BMP can't deal with transparency, layers or, as techie007 said, >8bit colors. Try flattening the image, and switching to 8bit palette mode .

Comment: Why would you ever want to use BMP?

Answer (score 3):

Change your colour mode to RGB and 8 Bits/Channel (Image > Mode > RGB Color), then you should get the BMP option in the drop down box when you use 'Save As'.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how or why you're having issues, but I am able to save a multilayer image with transparencies as a BMP while using Adobe Photoshop CS5e. Of course, the transparency will go away with a BMP, but I still at least have the option.

[image]

And, Photoshop does support BMP 32bit Images

[image]

Comment: He's having the issues because he doesn't have Windows.

Comment: It's also shown as an option in my version of Photoshop CS5 for OS X.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Mac vs Windows. The BMP option is available if you have your color mode set to RGB and 8 Bits/Channel, independent of the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

This works under Mac on Photoshop CS6.  Set the color mode to RGB and 8 Bits/Channel.  You can then save as BMP.   You'll get the BMP options dialog once you save.